# Jquery ajax send data and get: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I have this jquery ajax code which send data to server to update fields:

```
$(function() { 
    $('#addFieldForm2').submit(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();

        if ( $(this).parsley('validate') ) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "updateUsluga.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: true, 
            data: { ajdi:ajdi,opis:$("#opis1").val(),kolicina:$("#kolicina1").val(),jmere:$("#jmere1").val(),cena:$("#cena1").val(),popust:$("#popust1").val(),porez:$("#pdv1").val(),valuta:$("#valuta1").val()},           
            dataType: "html",

            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('#izmeni').modal('hide');
               $('#example').dataTable().fnDestroy();
                drawVisualization();
            },
```

And I send As I can see from browser console (network tab) this data:

```
ajdi=24&opis=decimalni+broj1&kolicina=10&jmere=h&cena=11.50&popust=5&porez=5&valuta=Din
```

my updateUsluga.php file is:

```
 try {        
                $STH = $db->prepare("UPDATE usluge SET opis=:1, jmere=:2, kol=:3, cena=:4, valuta:=7, popust=:5, porez=:6 WHERE ID=:id AND user_id=:8");
                $STH->bindParam(':id', $_POST['ajdi']);
                $STH->bindParam(':1', $_POST['opis']);
                $STH->bindParam(':2', $_POST['jmere']);

                $STH->bindParam(':3', $_POST['kolicina']);
                $STH->bindParam(':4', $_POST['cena']);
                $STH->bindParam(':5', $_POST['popust']);
                $STH->bindParam(':6', $_POST['porez']);
        $STH->bindParam(':7', $_POST['valuta']);
                $STH->bindParam(':8', $user_id);


                $STH->execute();

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
            echo "<p>Data submitted successfully</p>";
```

but when I try to run this code I just get:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens<p>Data submitted successfully</p>
```

I know what this error means but I dont see any misstke into my code. Please help me to solve this easy but strange problem.

Problem is becouse I dont see any error in my code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$STH = $db->prepare("UPDATE usluge SET opis=:1, jmere=:2, kol=:3, cena=:4, valuta:=7, popust=:5, porez=:6 WHERE ID=:id AND user_id=:8");
```

you have a typo on `valuta:=7` i think it must be `valuta=:7`

Comment: wow, thaks very much, I was so blind. I try to solve this problem all day!